# pass var to wp_mail template function

Tags: php, wordpress

I've following functions:

```
add_action('frm_after_create_entry', 'dmdSendTestKeyZGS', 30, 2);
function dmdSendTestKeyZGS($entry_id, $form_id){
    global $wpdb;
    if($form_id == 13){
        global $wpdb;
        $myrow = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM mi_zgskeys WHERE used = 0", ARRAY_A);
        $id = $myrow['id'];
        $key = $myrow['key']; //KEY IS STORED
        $wpdb->query("UPDATE mi_zgskeys SET used = 1 WHERE id = $id");
        $body = get_email_body_wpse_96357($key); 
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        if(isset($_POST['item_meta'][96]))
            wp_mail($_POST['item_meta'][96], 'test', $body, $headers);
    }
}

function get_email_body_wpse_96357($key) {
    $body = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
    <title>Ihr Test-Lizenzschlüssel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p><a><?php echo $key; ?></p> //$key EMPTY???
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>";
    return $body;
}
```

Can somebody tell me why the `$key` in my template is empty?

If I send an E-Mail the field isn't filled and not sure why.

Comment: Some obvious things: This is not the way WordPress intends you to do such things. Instead of brutally forcing WordPress to eat your function, you should make use of the add_filter function to give it your parameters one step before and then fire the wp_mail function.

Comment: What is the content of `var_dump($myrow)`? Is it null? Is the column name correct?

Comment: @HenryA. $myrow is filled and correct.

Comment: Ah okay. Without <?php echo ?> it works fine. So I only need to include the $key var... And of course. I don't need that because it is PHP....

Answer (score 0):

just replace the *`<?php echo $key; ?>`* to *`$key`*.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing